# Excel 2007: Loading data from web; append, not replace

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I made a web service that generates a data table that I periodically want to download into Excel. Because there is a huge amout of old data, I don't want to always generate everything - only data for dates which have not been downloaded yet.

If I last downloaded data into Excel two days ago, the next time I hit refresh, I want Excel to **append** the existing table, **not replace** the existing data with the new data. The web service is set up so that it will only generate data that has not previously been requested.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2010 so it may be different, but the XML Map Properties may get you where you want to go -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ben Jones. Look at the external Data Range properties.
[image]